# Need help focusing question

Tags: support

This [question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/88473/32436) has four close votes.  Back when it had one close vote, I attempted to explain why it was not a duplicate of a similar question.  I'd like to ask for some help editing it so it's clearer why it should remain open.

Answer (score 3):

To start with, in my opinion, much of the question is irrelevant backstory. It might be cleaner to strip that out when thinking about the question. That said, as I will discuss below, I think it is a pretty clear duplicate, so it might be better to use the backstory to highlight why it is a new question.

In [your question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/88473/want-to-do-mathematical-physics-if-first-choice-dept-not-a-good-fit-can-i-swi) you ask

> How hard would it be to apply to switch over to a math department (either in the same university, or a different one), assuming I had taken sufficient math courses, and done very well in them?

The [*duplicate question*](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/6032/switching-from-one-area-of-graduate-study-to-another) asks

> For example, suppose someone has enrolled in a computer science phd program. Can he switch over to math(or physics) phd program in the same school later?

I find it hard to see how your question is not a duplicate. You argument that your question is unique seems to be that you *would like to see a specific focus on the math/physics interface*. I think this is covered in an [answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/6034/929) to the duplicate

> Other factors that can mitigate or complicate this process: if there's a standard procedure for doing this, if the two departments historically are comfortable with movement back and forth, if the departments are in the same college/school within the university, and so on.

In my opinion, there is nothing special about the math/physics interface. Math and Physics departments sometimes get along and sometimes do not get along. At that level, the answer is really going to depend on the actual departments.